# How to pass `self` to PropertyMock?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

When mocking a function, I can pass `self` with `autospec=True`:

```
def do_thing_side_effect(self):
  pass

mocker.patch('module.class.do_thing', side_effect=do_thing_side_effect, autospec=True)
```

When mocking a property getter, I am unable to pass `self` with either `autospec=True` or `spec=True`:

```
def thing_side_effect(self):
  pass

mocker.patch('module.class.thing', new=mocker.PropertyMock(side_effect=thing_side_effect, autospec=True))
```

This yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 2848, in __get__
    return self()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1092, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1096, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1157, in _execute_mock_call
    result = effect(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: thing_side_effect() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Using `spec` instead of `autospec` causes the same error:

```
from module import class

def thing_side_effect(self):
  pass

mocker.patch('module.class.thing', new=mocker.PropertyMock(side_effect=thing_side_effect, spec=class.thing))
```

Using `spec` + `new_callable` instead of `new` causes the same error:

```
from module import class

def thing_side_effect(self):
  pass

mocker.patch('module.class.thing', spec=mocker.create_autospec(class.thing, side_effect=thing_side_effect, new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)
```

Comment: You examples don't show that `thing_side_effect` is actually a method.  self is only passed implicitly if it is actually a method belonging to a class.

Comment: That is incorrect. `self` is passed to a side effect when autospeccing, even when it is a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, in your case i think it would be best to use patch.object

```
with patch.object(module.class, 'thing_side_effect', new_callable=PropertyMock) as thing_side_effect_mock:
    thing_side_effect_mock.side_effect = "what ever you want to return here"
```

Good luck :)

Comment: Why would `mocker.patch.object` work? (It doesn't.) Isn't the only difference with `mocker.patch` that it takes a reference? Thanks for your reply anyway.